# PHP PDO SQLITE3, PDO::getAttribute , warning: Driver does not support this function

Tags: php, pdo, sqlite

I set up SQLITE3 with PDO as following:

```
$this->pdo = new \PDO("sqlite:" . Config::PATH_TO_SQLITE_FILE);
$this->pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT, Config::SQLITE_TIMEOUT);
```

where :

```
class Config 
{
   /**
    * path to the sqlite file
    */
   const PATH_TO_SQLITE_FILE = 'db/mDB.db';
   const SQLITE_TIMEOUT = 10000;
}
```

The point is everything works fine but I'm not sure if **ATTR_TIMEOUT** attribute is set true without any problem
So I decided to use getAttribute:

> $this->pdo->getAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT)

but it is exhibited that the driver does not support this function

> Warning: PDO::getAttribute(): SQLSTATE[IM001]: Driver does not support
>   this function: driver does not support that attribute

So, How can I be convinced that attribute was set truly?